# Is there an easier way to create this shape?

Tags: modeling

I don't know how I can make these grooves/slots. Is there an easier way to cut the plane? I'm new to Blender, so I feel I must be missing something. This geometry is too complicated. There may be a way to clean up the mesh and avoid these distorted edges? Thanks.
[image: image sample]

[image: shape of face]

Here the face I'm working on.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the knife tool?

Comment: The main issue is that all the edges don't stay straight, they need to be attached to the corners of the rectangle.

Comment: I suppose those "distorted edges" are created by the subsurf modifier... so it's not real geometry, it's an algorithmic calculated subdivision.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKJ-ml5N0fw Try the knife project tool

Comment: Yes it's only created by the Subsurf modifier. So what is wrong wiith my workflow? How can I create this shapes?

Comment: @10 Replies. How can I use the knife tool? I need to create a rectangle mesh and use it as a template to cut the face?

Comment: @Grobby yeah.. and since you want an indent, you would fill the hole, and move the filled vertices into the mesh

Comment: But what will change this method in comparison with what I did? I mean I will need to attach the hole created to the corners of the main face. I suppose that the hole created with the knife tool won't hover in the face as if by magic?

Comment: plz attach the file

Comment: @Grobby Can you share the model (or just the shown part) eg by http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com?